# Unexpected behavior from pointers

Tags: pointers, argv, calloc, atoi

So what I am trying to do is to allocate contiguous space of memory, and then initializing it with arguments from command line, but it seems I have some issues with the assignment of values to the vector. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* args[]) 
{
    int dim;
    printf("Enter size of the block: ");
    scanf("%d", &dim);

    int* m1 = calloc(dim, sizeof(int));
    if(m1 == NULL)                     
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        m1[i] = (atoi)args[i + 1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        printf("m1's value %d: %d\n", i,*(m1 + i));
    }


    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it it gives me 1 warning and 1 error

```
Es6.c:20:10: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
m1[i] = (atoi)args[i + 1];
      ^
Es6.c:20:18: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘args’
m1[i] = (atoi)args[i + 1];
```

I'm using atoi to convert the argument (located in args) in int.
Is m1 a vector? For all I know it's a pointer to the start of a vector that I initialized with calloc, if that's correct, then why is it giving me problems?
When I change:

```
m1[i] = (atoi)args[i + 1];
```

to

```
m1[i] = *args[i + 1];
```

it works, but the results are nothing like the arguments that I passed.
My guess it's that I'm passing the address and not the actual arguments stored in it.
P.s.
When I pass the arguments from a file it gives me back segmentation fault, why is that?(This with the *args[i + 1] implementation.

Comment: Don't you mean `atoi(args[i + 1]);`? `atoi` is a function.

Comment: I thought it was a type caster

Comment: @MrBens Now it works with parameters passed from the command line thank you  :) but I still have a problem, when I try to pass it through a .txt file it doesn't work, it still gives me segmentation fault. I called my txt file "Es6.txt". I then use the following command line instruction: "a.out < Es6.txt". The txt file has 6 lines, each with a single integer in it, which woud be the arguments.